# How to Autowire SessionFactory without spring config

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I want Autowired SessionFactory, I study spring on the course and there it is done using spring config like this [DataSource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAlfK.jpg) and [SessionFactory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHznS.jpg).
What should I do to create this by Java class @Component or like this?

This is my SessionFactory
 `private SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration()
                                        .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                                        .addAnnotatedClass(Customer .class)
                                        .buildSessionFactory();`

and [hibernate.cfg.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pCoF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use @PersistenceContext annotation like this:

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;
```

You also need a TransactionManager.

See [this](https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-and-jpa) for details.

Comment: [I had tried to do this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSJAj.png), but i need autowire

Comment: @ДенисБурмистров That's wrong. See the link I gave you.

Comment: @ДенисБурмистров No